# Android - control list of 2nd Spinner item select based on 1st spinner selection

Tags: android

I am using 2 spinners in my app, 1st spinner is an array of `lecturer`, and 2nd spinner is an array of `courses`,

and this is an output of json in 1st spiner:
    ardi halim, fanny, indah, [...]

and for 2nd spinner output look like:
    mobile development, object-oriented programming, [...]

my question is how to control the 2nd spinner list when 1st spinner already select the `lecturer?

for the example :

1. when 1st spinner choose *ardi halim*, the 2nd spinner giving a list
   of *mobile development and OOP*
2. when 1st spinner choose *fanny*, the 2nd spinner giving a list of *mobile development* only

i just can control the 2nd spinner using `setSelected` with this code :

```
if(text.equals("Fanny")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Anda Memilih Dosen Fanny", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    sp2.setSelection(1);
                    sp2.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

but how to add more than 1 list in 2nd spinner when someone choose `ardi halim`?

I've tried searching for a posting someone who has the same problem but I have not found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make class like this for handling 2nd spinner according to your 1st spinner result

```
public class Lecturer{
String name;
ArrayList course;
Lecturer(String name,Arraylist course){
this.name= name;
this.course = course;
    }

public String toString(){
return name;
}
}
```

In Activity

```
ArrayList<Lecturer> lecturerList = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Lecturer("ardi halim",<courses list for ardi halim>));
list.add(new Lecturer("fanny",<courses list for fanny>));

set lecturerList for 1st spinner
then
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ArrayList courselist = ((Lecturer)spinner1.getSelectedItem()).course;
                set courselist for spinner2 adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: it cant be more simple to do with `if else` statement sir? i have read about `getSelectionItem` to displaying a list by position, is it possible to use?

Comment: If i am understanding your question right.. In spinner1 onItemSelected method you can call
'spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()' and by using if else or switch, set array for 2nd adapter but it would not be the best solution

Comment: ohhh, thats can be another solution for me, thanks for ur suggest, ill try ur answer and ur suggested,

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

Make 2 different array of lectures or fixed the position of lectures,
then on basis of selection of first spinner you can set the array to the next spinner or set the position to next spinner.

Comment: so it's impossible to add `getSelectedItem` for 2 or more list?